# playAtTime is not working, but play() is with AVAudioPlayer() in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I run my app with just musicPlayer.play() there is no issue, but I want the app to start at a specific point and when I use playAtTime(timeToPlay) the audio never plays. I have attached the top portion of my code (which I believe is the only relevant portion). Any help would be awesome!

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

class RHCPViewController: UIViewController {

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
var isPlaying: Bool = false
var timer: NSTimer?
var timeToPlay: NSTimeInterval = 0.00

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden =  true

}


@IBAction func playButtonWasClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    if isPlaying == false {
        let song = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CantStop", ofType: "mp3")!)

        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: song, fileTypeHint: nil)
            backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            backgroundMusicPlayer.playAtTime(timeToPlay)
            isPlaying = true
        }

        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
```

Comment: Helps to read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/playAtTime: They even give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `0.0` to `playAtTime`, but the time parameter must be greater than the audio device's current time. Use the `deviceCurrentTime` property in computing the time parameter as follows:

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.playAtTime(backgroundMusicPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + timeToPlay)
```

See also the [API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/playAtTime:).